# EJB 3.0 CMP Transaction after a rollback

Tags: ejb-3.0

I'm having some trouble with transaction management in EJB3.0. What I want to do is to log an error into the database in case an exception happens.

For that purpose I have 2 stateless beans: `Bean A` and `Bean B`.

Bean A does the following:

1. save something
2. call `Bean B` to log an error if needed

In Step 1, the save is basically using the `EntityManager#merge(-)` method.
In Step 2, I have put the following lines at the top of `Bean B`:

```
@Stateless(name = "ErrorLogDAO", mappedName = "ErrorLogDAO")
@Remote
@Local
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class ErrorLogDAOBean {...}
```

However, when an exception is taking place in the save method, I'm catching it and then I manually invoke the `ctx.setRollBackOnly()` method and after that I call `ErrorLogDAOBean` that inserts an error log to the DB. But the error log is not being inserted and the error I'm getting is:

> javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: EJB Exception: :
>   weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException     at
>   weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:551)
>     at
>   weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionManagerImpl.java:319)
>     at
>   weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionManagerImpl.java:312)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTATransactionController.markTransactionForRollback_impl(JTATransactionController.java:145)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractTransactionController.markTransactionForRollback(AbstractTransactionController.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.rollbackTransaction(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4486)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1351)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:468)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithPreBuiltChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1439)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:316)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:527)
>   ....

I'm well familiar with transaction management logic, and based on the code above I assumed I had this covered, but it appears not.

Any ideas?

## UPDATE

Bean A Code:

```
@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(value = REQUIRED)
public class WMServiceBOBean {

public void saveInBeanA {

     int errorCode = save();

     if (errorCode != SUCCESS)
     { 
   ClassX.logError();
   ctx.setRollbackOnly();
   return errorCode;
     }
   }
}
```

Class X Code:

```
public class classX
{
 ...
 public void logError()
 {
   ErrorLog e = new ErrorLog;
   BeanB beanB = //Local lookup of Bean B
   beanB.insertErrorLog (e);
 }
 ...
}
```

BEAN B Code:

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class ErrorLogDAOBean
{
 ...
 public void insertErrorLog (ErrorLog e)
 {
   merge (e);
 }
 ...
}
```

Comment: You really should not put `@Remove` and `@Local` on bean class. The no-value versions of these annotations are to be used on business interfaces - on class they should specify the interfaces `Class` objects. Is the exception thrown from the logging bean or during setRollbackOnly? I assume that BeanA has CMT?

Comment: The exception thrown is from the logging bean and yes BeanA has CMT

Comment: Can you fix your annotations and show the code that throws this exception (as well as the one that invokes the `ErrorLogDAOBean`)?

Comment: Pitor, i dont understand what you're saying about the annotations! ErrorLogDAOBean is a session bean that has both local and remote interfaces. These annotations are auto-generated when this session bean was created.

Comment: Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Remote.html).

Comment: Ok thx. As for the code, well here's what happens: BeanA calls a normal JAVA class (not a session. In this JAVA class we do the following: Create a POJO object called ErrorLog, then call BeanB which has a method that takes in this POJO and uses the merge method to insert an ErrorLog to the DB

Comment: From what you've written - you use non-EJB method to create `ErrorLog` and from within this class you invoke `BeanB`. How do you do it? Could you update your question and show some relevant code for BeanA and BeanB? It should help to understand your problem.

Comment: Piotr, i've updated the original question to include a bit of code

Comment: Any answer on this? Anyone? @PiotrNowicki?

Comment: Can you post your 'local lookup' of `ErrorLogBean`? Is this a SLSB? Can you check if `ErrorLogBean` works in the same transaction as `Bean A`?

Comment: Yes ErrorLogBean is a SLSB. As for the local lookup its being done as such: ErrorLogDAO bean = (ErrorLogDAO) context.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/ErrorLogDAO");

Comment: Can you check if your `ErrorLogBean` is invoked in different Transaction than Bean 1? I've described it more-or-less here: http://piotrnowicki.com/2011/11/am-i-in-the-same-transaction-am-i-using-the-same-persistencecontext/

Comment: Piotr, in order to use the TransactionSynchronizationRegistry i need to add the reference in weblogic-ejb-jar.xml. I tried to do that but with no success. Do you know where i can find the correct way to add the reference?

Comment: I have no idea how to configure it, as I have never used Weblogic...

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the problem.

Here's the problem, when looking up the ErrorLogBean, i was instantiating a new Persistence Manager. When the transaction gets flagged for rollback, the process of getting a new PM was failing. I know it doesn't make sense to get a new Persistence Manager but it was part of test we are conducting.

Thanks Piotr for all your help in this!